# Does the order of the pixels drawn depend on the indices in glDrawElements?

Tags: opengl

I'm drawing several alpha-blended triangles that overlap with a single `glDrawElements` call.

The indices list the triangles back to front and this order is important for the correct visualization.

Can I rely on the result of this operation being exactly the same as when drawing the triangles in the same order with distinct draw calls?

I'm asking this because I'm not sure whether some hardware would make some kind of an optimization and use the indices only for the information about the primitives that are drawn and disregard the actual primitive order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on the order being the same as specified in the index array, and that fragments will be correctly blended with the results of triangles specified earlier in the array.

I cannot find a reference for this, but my UI rendering code relies on this behaviour (and I think it is a common technique).

Comment: I too searched a lot for this and could find a reference. And all the experiments on my graphics card do seem to confirm this.

Have you tested your UI rendering on multiple devices? Even the most contemporary ones?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is correct. My only doubt is not finding an explicit guarantee in the spec. It might be implied by Appendix A (Invariance), but I don't think so. My current code using this has only been run on an Nvidia 560 & a RasberryPi (using ES 2). I think I have used this technique in the past for projects released to the public (sorry - long time ago). I do remember asking exactly this and receiving this answer. Also I remember reading about a pipeline sorting pixels by primitive before blending into the destination buffer. Sorry I can't be less vague.

Answer (score 12):

To second GuyRT's answer, I looked through the [GL4.4 core spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf):

`glDrawElements` is described as follows (emphasis mine):

> This command constructs a ***sequence* of geometric primitives** by
>   successively transferring elements for count vertices to the GL.

In section  2.1, on can find the following statement (emphasis mine):

> Commands are always processed in the order in which they are received,
>   [...] **This means, for example, that one primitive must be drawn
>   completely before any subsequent one can affect the framebuffer.**

One *might* read this as only valid for primitves rendered through different draw calls (commands), however, in 7.12.1, there is some further confirmation for the more general interpretation  reading for that statement (again, my emphasis):

> The relative order of invocations of the same shader type are
>   undefined. A store issued by a shader when working on primitive B
>   might complete prior to a store for primitive A, even if primitive A
>   is specified prior to primitive B. This applies even to fragment
>   shaders; **while fragment shader outputs are written to the framebuffer
>   in primitive order**, stores executed by fragment shader invocations are
>   not.

Comment: Well done finding those passages. I think together they provide good (even conclusive) support for order-of-fragments-belonging-to-primitives-within-a-draw-call being well defined.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge OpenGL makes no statement about the order of triangles rendered within a single draw call of any kind.  It would be counterproductive of it to do so, because it would place undesirable constraints on implementations.

Consider that modern rendering hardware is almost always multi-processor, so the individual triangles from a draw call are almost certainly being rendered in parallel.  If you need to render in a particular order for alpha blending purposes, you need to break up your geometry.  Alternatively you could investigate the variety of order independent transparency algorithms out there.

Comment: I thought so too, but curiously enough my graphics card (Radeon HD 4870) does seem to follow the indices and produced a correct result for the couple of tests I made. It is old, but still... :) It may be just luck.

That's what led me to ask the question.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect, but I can't find a direct reference for it. IIRC a conforming OpenGL implementation must produce output as if each triangle was rendered in the order given by the indices, and drivers go to considerable effort to make sure this is so.